# Sending Emails with Rails API & AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, actionmailer

I've been rebuilding a rails site with an Angular front end.

Is there an angular-way to do emails? I was trying to send them through the rails server, but now all my rails url helpers are screwed up by the difference between the angular url routes and the rails API routes. Do I use angular? Do I use rails url helpers somehow? Or do I manually update each route with this gnarly pattern:

```
<a href="<%= root_path + "/posts/" + @post.id %">Link to Post</a>
```

Thanks!